# Crispy FormHelper Wrap in Div

Tags: html, css, django, django-crispy-forms

Trying to wrap my first_name and last_name fields with a div that has a class added to it.

The form helper itself is working, because the 'id-exampleForm' and 'blueforms' is added to the form div, but it won't generate the custom div around the two fields.

```
# Customize Crispy forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Fieldset, ButtonHolder, Submit, HTML, Field, Div
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import (
    PrependedText, PrependedAppendedText, FormActions)

class ReservationForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name', required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last Name', required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReservationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id = 'id-exampleForm'
        self.helper.form_class = 'blueForms'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            #Div('first_name', style="background: white;", title="Explication title", css_class="bigdivs")
            Field(
                Div(
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                css_id = 'special-fields',
                style="background: white;",
                css_class="bigdivs"
        ),
    )
```

Comment: Wonder what's wrong, because I'm getting both form id/class and wrapper div with id/class properly set up.

Comment: Layout -> Div (with special css class) -> Field (with one of your fields, e.g. first_name), Field (second field). To me your order looks wrong.

Comment: It is actually working, my apologies... I had to dig deeper into the html.